# Kubernetes MongoDB operator - "Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version"

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have set up the Kubernetes MongoDB operator according to this guide: https://adamtheautomator.com/mongodb-kubernetes/ and it works well. However, when I try to update the MongoDB version to 6.0.4, I get the following error:

```
{
"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: 
Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: 
{ _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.4\" }. 
See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. 
:: caused by :: Invalid feature compatibility version value, expected '5.0' or '5.3' or '6.0. 
See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). 
If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 5.0, see the documentation on upgrading at
 https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0/#upgrade-procedures."}
```

I have followed this guide: https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/deploy-configure.md#upgrade-your-mongodbcommunity-resource-version-and-feature-compatibility-version

This means that my `config/samples/arbitrary_statefulset_configuration/mongodb.com_v1_hostpath.yaml` file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mdb0
spec:
  members: 2
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "6.0.4"
  featureCompatibilityVersion: "6.0"
  security:
    ...
```

The rest is set according to the linked guide (in the first link above).

The error that is thrown suggests that, for whatever reason, the `featureCompatibilityVersion` field is ignored, even though I have explicitly set it to `"6.0"`. However, since the documentation clearly states that this is a possible configuration, this shouldn't be the case. My question then is: am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days' research, I managed to find a way to do this, and it is annoyingly simple...

The key to all of this lies in the documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#default-values). Basically, in order to update from mongo 4.4.0 to 6.0.4, you need to do it in steps:

First, change the mongo version from "4.4.0" to e.g. "5.0.4", whilst setting the featureCompatibilityVersion to "5.0":

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mdb0
spec:
  version: "5.0.4"
  featureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0"
...
```

After having applied this, verify that the featureCompatibilityVersion is indeed 5.0 and that all MongoDB pods are "5.0.4". If the MongoDB pods aren't "5.0.4", you need to restart the service (See "**Restarting everything**" below). You can now run the second step:

Update the mongo version to "6.0.4" and the featureCompatibilityVersion to "6.0":

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mdb0
spec:
  version: "6.0.4"
  featureCompatibilityVersion: "6.0"
...
```

Apply this change and verify that the featureCompatibilityVersion is indeed 6.0, and that all MongoDB pods are "6.0.4". Once again, if the pods aren't "6.0.4", **Restart everything** according to the procedure below.

---

#### Checking feature compatibility version

The easiest way to do this is to:

1. Port-forward the mongodb connection to your host: `kubectl port-forward service/mdb0-svc -n mongodb 27017:27017` (according to the guide).
2. Install mongosh on your host (if you haven't done so already).
3. Run the following query: `mongosh -u mongoadmin -p secretpassword --eval 'db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1})'` (if you're using the same credentials as the guide).

#### Restarting everything

During my development process, I had multiple occasions where I had to restart everything. Here's my way of doing that:

1. Delete the config's resources: `kubectl delete -f config/samples/arbitrary_statefulset_configuration/mongodb.com_v1_hostpath.yaml -n mongodb` .
2. Whilst (1) is pending, execute the following lines of code to make (1) being able to finish:

```
kubectl patch pv data-volume-0 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
kubectl patch pv data-volume-1 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
kubectl patch pv data-volume-2 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
kubectl patch pv logs-volume-0 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
kubectl patch pv logs-volume-1 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
kubectl patch pv logs-volume-2 -p "{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}" -n mongodb
```

3. Run the following lines of code:

```
kubectl delete deployments.apps mongodb-kubernetes-operator -n mongodb
kubectl delete crd mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com
kubectl apply -f config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml
kubectl apply -k config/rbac/ -n mongodb
kubectl create -f config/manager/manager.yaml -n mongodb
kubectl apply -f new-user.yaml -n mongodb
kubectl apply -f config/samples/arbitrary_statefulset_configuration/mongodb.com_v1_hostpath.yaml -n mongodb
```